# How to download firefox addon(Firebug) from another computer?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I like to download Firebug to my personal computer but whenever i try to download a addon it ask me to allow to install on the same system. My problem is i don't have internet connection in my room so i want download it from my friend system to mine. Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found a way to download a addon.
just go to google and search for a addon

u will get link : https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.11/
go to that page and right click on .xpi file and click (save link as)  it will now ask you to save the file. just save the file on your system and go to firefox->tools-->addons-->
there near search u can see a dropdown and in that dropdown click-->install add on from file using browse.. thats all like this u can download addon and install anywhere.